# Active record ruby on rails error

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems

I have not gone too far with the development of the application.
i just did `rails new app -d mysql` and i did `rails s` loaded my browser.

Rails homepage loaded and I went inside my app folder, `http://localhost:3000/demo/index` and surprised to see this error `ActiveRecord::ConnectionNotEstablished`. 
Please suggest some good way to get out of this and continue with my further development.

OS is Windows 7, I already installed mysql adapter and tried many solutions over the stackoverflow similar questions. None are solving my issue. I request serious help.
My database.yml looks like this with regards to development:

```
development:
  adapter: mysql2
  encoding: utf8
  reconnect: false
  database: app_development
  pool: 5
  username: root
  password: pass
  host: localhost
```

Comment: Are you sure your mysql server is running?

Comment: First off, have you installed a MySQL server?

Comment: Yes, i did install and i configured it to have a password of word "pass" and i'm able to go into my mysql folder and the command line works fine too, i had a problem with mysqllib.dll and i fixed it too. Now, this one's popping up.

Comment: Type something like "C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.0\bin\mysqld" in the Windows command line. Sorry for not being more specific, but I'm not used to Windows environments

Comment: That's ok. But It's still the same. I shutdown webrick, literally deleted the `server.pid` since it wasnt shutting down. And still its the same after i start it. i did `bundle install` after adding the adding `gem 'mysql'` , still nope. :(

Comment: I got my xampp to run mysql too just in the background.

Comment: your adapter is mysql2 so in Gemfile it will be `gem mysql2` and do bundle install and try

Comment: what is your `mysql2` adapter's version.. is it like this `mysql2-0.3.11-x86-mingw32`....?

Comment: It sounds like `mysql2` install problems, but you claim its fixed. can you get into `rails c` console? If you can access via console this is a quick way to verify.

Comment: I switched to Ubuntu and everything works fine now. Thanks for all your help. Windows is just so buggy.

Answer (score 0):

After creating application, create database using below command

```
 rake db:create
```

and then start server using `rails s`

Answer (score 0):

I switched to Ubuntu after trying number of methods to solve the issue on windows. Solved.